# Detecting farm crop boundaries from satellite images

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network

I want to detect crop areas from satellite images.

If we copy any image of google maps that contains a farm land, you can easily see the divisions, but using OpenCV is not so easy for me.

First, I convert the image from RGB to gray and apply a Gaussian filter.

[image]

When I apply a threshold to the image, I get many irregularities that make it difficult to separate the different areas.

[image]

I had thought about clicking somewhere and use some flood algorithm to detect at least the edges of the terrain clicked. Another (more advanced) option is to use CNN but I still do not have much experience in that and I would like to start with the basics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would also include a process which leverages the input color which will help identify crop areas ... specifically a crop field will tend to be uniform as opposed to varied on non crop

Comment: It is a good idea! I'm just starting with OpenCV and almost all the examples I saw were working in black and white, so I had not taken into account the use of RGB information. I'm going to look for some clustering algorithm that works on the 3 channels and the spatial location of the point

Comment: google mask r-cnn satellite. there is a paper about house segmentation training but probably works for farm crop segmentation too

Comment: Do you have any annotated data to train on? Would it be feasible to obtain such data somehow?

Comment: did you solve this? If yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

Consider,
1) Breaking the image up into many small images
2) Increasing the strength of your gaussian filter to remove noise
3) Using hough line detector to get edges from the binary image (black and white)

You will need to get the image as clean as possible. By clean I mean, make sure the edges are very clean with minimal noise on the inside of the fields.

Lastly I would suggest using an edge detector with a hough line detector. Look into [canny](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) edge detection.

Comment: Seems to be a good approach. I'll try it and leave you the comments. Thanks!